# WPF Grid Elements not resizing when another one is set to collapsed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visibility

I am using a Grid to balance 3 parts. The first two shall take up each 50% of the remaining space, the last two shall stay the same height at the bottom, as it is a bar with buttons.

I use a GridSplitter to allow dynamic resizing between the first two elements, but removing it doesnt change anything either.

Here is a minimal working example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPFApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPFApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="firstBox"
            Grid.Row="0"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            AcceptsTab="True"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <GridSplitter x:Name="splitter" Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        <TextBox 
            x:Name="secondBox"
            Grid.Row="2"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            AcceptsTab="True"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Collapse" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
namespace TestWPFApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            splitter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            secondBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

After clicking the button, the second textbox and the gridsplitter collapse, so I cannot use them anymore (desired), but the remaining textbox does not take up the rest of the space (undesired).

In my understanding as the row has a star for height, it should automatically adjust its space. Do I need to call a function like updateUI or something so that the first textbox gets automatically resized?

Answer (score 2):

You observe such behaviour, cause the heights of first and third grid row is set to '*'. After setting 2nd `textBox`Visibility to collapsed 3rd grid row is not disappears. So if you write in `Button_Click` event handler something like this, all should work like expected.

```
rootGrid.RowDefinitions[2].MaxHeight = 0;
```

I can suggest to use `DataBinding` for it property to achieve this. You can bind second `TextBox` `Visibility` property to third RowDefinition `MaxHeight` property with `ValueConverter`. But I don't know the restrictions of your project.

Comment: While that does work and the top box is resized, this means i have to save the value. I dont see why I would need the DataBinding part, as the content of the MWE is in TabItem in my project and I only want to supply a possibility to reduce the second textbox to have more space in the first. Can you explain why this is needed? Or why it is not working as i expected.

Comment: If you'd like, you can write this in code behind, if you don't like to set `MaxHeight` manually you can write `Binding`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Well I implemented this in the function because I need to save the value of MaxHeight for showing the textbox again. I will however wait for more answers as I consider this more a workaround then a solution. Upvoted though

Comment: Ok then, to recollapse you should set `MaxHeight` to big value 2000 for example. Not clear but works.

Comment: Nice workaround, which solved my problem. But instead of using a random big value to show the textbox again you can use `double.PositiveInfinity`.